# What do I have to show still to prove that $x_t$ is stationary and ergodic?

Tags: stationarity, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, ergodic

Let $x_t=\varphi x_{t−1}+\varepsilon_t$ be the model with errors being white noise. If model is correctly specified and $|\varphi|<1$, why is $x_t$ not stationary and ergodic? Why cannot I use Krengel's theorem here? Do I also need to show that $\mathbb{E}(\log|\varepsilon_t|)<\infty$?